# Handling concurrent UDP DatagramReceivedFcn executions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, udp, datagram

I'm attempting to read ocean depth values at multiple frequencies which are being broadcast via UDP packets.  What I'm doing is telling the logging program to return the depth values to a specific UDP port, then use the DatagramReceivedFcn to run a function when data is received and essentially save that depth.

```
u1 = udp(remoteip,dataport18,'ByteOrder','littleEndian','LocalPort',dataport18,'DatagramTerminateMode','off');
set(u1,'InputBufferSize',6000);
u1.DatagramReceivedFcn = {@receivedata18};
fopen(u1);
```

Thus, when data is received on the port specified in 'dataport18', it will run the function receivedata18().  However, I'm trying to read depth data for multiple frequencies, so I create additional UDP objects:

```
u2 = udp(remoteip,dataport38,'ByteOrder','littleEndian','LocalPort',dataport38,'DatagramTerminateMode','off');
set(u2,'InputBufferSize',6000);
u2.DatagramReceivedFcn = {@receivedata38};
fopen(u2);
```

What I'm finding though is that only data for u1 (18 kHz) is being saved.  My guess is that since both frequencies ping at the same time, they both send their UDP packets and try to evaluate their respective functions at the same time, which Matlab is not capable of doing.

Is this indeed what is going on?  If so, is there any way around this issue so that I can concurrently read depth data that is being sent at the same time from two separate UDP packets?

Thanks!

**Update**

I'm wondering if I would need the Parallel Computing Toolbox in order to perform this.  I have a similar program in Python that is performed in essentially the same way, however it has no issues.  I'm assuming that it must be that Matlab can't run simultaneous functions without the Parallel Computing Toolbox

Comment: What are the receivedata38/18 functions? What do they do? Do you pass the correct reference to the udp object to them? Maybe they access the same buffer? Also, what do you mean by "frequency"? I believe that you must use asynchronous modes for the objects in order for your code to work properly.

Comment: The receivedata18/38 functions are bound to the u1 and u2 object, repsectively.  Therefore, when data is received on the u1 and u2 ports, those functions are ran and read the input buffer on u1 and u2.  So yes, they are passed the correct reference.  They only access the same buffer if I set dataport18 equal to dataport38.  Perhaps I need to look into using the asynchronous mode.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I should update this in case anyone cares.  It's not really an answer to my question, but what I'm currently doing that's working.

Instead of having the data sent to different UDP port, I simply have them sent to the same port and then read them sequentially.  Thus I'm not reading them synchronously, although that doesn't really slow down the operation much at all.